# MediaStore.Media.Images Android/ Kotlin: How to hide photos saved in gallery from user?

Tags: android, mediastore

I am using the following program to capture an image using the `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE cameraIntent`.

Code:

```
val values = ContentValues()
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture")
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From the Camera")
imageUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
//camera intent
val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE)
```

I have the following questions:

- The image that has been captured is being shown in the gallery. How do I hide that from the user?
- After taking the image, I am setting the photo in a `ImageView` that is lagging the activity. How can I compress the image when I am setting it to the `ImageView`?
- Is there a way to click photos only in potrait mode?

I tried changing the `EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`but that gives me the following warning: `Writing to internal storage is not supported android`

Comment: "The image that has been captured is being shown in the gallery. How do I hide that from the user?" -- do not put them in the gallery in the first place. This may require you to stop using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, because the user's chosen camera app can do whatever it wants. Photos are already compressed; consider using an image-loading library (such as Glide, Picasso, or Coil) for populating your `ImageView`. And the user can do whatever the user wants with their chosen camera app, including taking pictures in landscape. Use CameraX or another library if you need more control over the camera.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thanks for the suggestions and insight, will look into these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you use the media store they are in 'the gallery'.

So you have to use getFilesDir() and classic file methods to save them for your eyes only.

Answer (score 1):

> The image that has been captured is being shown in the gallery. How do
> I hide that from the user?

As [blackapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12121419/blackapps) have said, and in accordance to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage), which states that `MediaStore` API uses [shared storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared), you can't use `MediaStore` API to store in [app-specific storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific) (Not the Gallery).

This [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath) provides an example of storing photos to app specific storage using [`getExternalFileDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).

> After taking the image, I am setting the photo in a ImageView that is
> lagging the activity. How can I compress the image when I am setting
> it to the ImageView?

Try [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/), a fast and efficient image loading library for Android. In addition, as I'm typing this, [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) has also recommended other Image loading libraries such as Picasso and Coil.

> Is there a way to click photos only in portrait mode?

Perhaps this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59606488/11200630) might help. You can set the[`clickable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:clickable) attribute of the ImageView programmatically or declaratively.